# Really awful noise

Tags: serpentine-belt, drive-belt

Every time I start the car there's this noise I don't know how to describe. It's there immediately upon start, during idle, while driving, constant. I have been ignoring it because everything works fine. Yesterday it got significantly worse. Now it sounds like a kitten set on fire or something.

I think it's coming from the belt or one of the pumps that run on it. The thing is, everything works perfectly. Power steering is fine, A/C is fine, no loss of power, no trouble starting, temperature seems fine, if it wasn't for the noise, you would have no idea anything is wrong. While the noise is constant, it seems to become louder when I shift gears.

Should I replace the belt and hope that was the issue or how would I determine the exact source of problem?

Comment: Can you upload a recording of the noise?

Comment: So the noise went back to what it was before. I think it's a transmission issue.

Comment: Shop said it was the water pump. Seems fine now after replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it could be the belt only, but very probable that one of the accessories the the belt turns is defective. The mechanic will remove the belt and check each pulley for worn bearings and alignment. He will probably find a defective accessory. Eventually driving with this noise will eventually cause the defective part to stop working and the belt will come off risking serious damage to your engine. The best thing to do is to address this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Doh. So you have to check them all. So as a bearing goes bad, it will still function perfectly then suddenly boom?